# How to get the value of a $total before the code calculated?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to show a content of variable whom been calculate in a `foreach` loop. The problem is that I want to echo it before the loop.

```
<?php
    echo $total; // note this line I want to appear the total count of loop. the problem is it cannot appear because it is in the above of foreach loop. I want to appear it in this above before foreach loop.
    $total = 0;
    foreach($pathList as $item) {
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($item);
        if(preg_match(strtolower('/\b'.$_POST['song'].'\b/'), strtolower($filename))) {
            $total = $total + 1; // the total count of foreach loop I want to appear in echo $total    
        }
        // some code
    }
?>
```

I do want to echo it inside the loop but only once after completed the loop.
Any idea how do I solve this problem? I tried `global $total` but not working...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use echo $total;  at the end of loop.

Comment: Didn't I see this same exact question earlier?

Comment: You can also store result in session then retrieve before start of loop.

Comment: you need the value of $total at the end of the loop or the last element of the array?

Comment: @Umar don't have an idea about session. I want to appear it above the loop. because if I put it at the end of loop it is appeared in the button of a page.

Comment: @djsoda: it will be good to have some know of sesssion. Some research effort is required form you.

Comment: _“I want to show a last result of foreach loop above its code.”_ - then I hope your time machine is all filled up & ready to go … But you can of course easily assemble whatever output you are currently making inside that loop, in a string variable instead of outputting it directly - then you can output the total followed by that other content afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally - **NO**. You cannot echo variable that not been calculate yet (synchronization in PHP).

If all you do in the `for-loop` regarding `$total` is increasing by 1 then you actually count the number of element in the array so you can just do:

```
echo count($pathList);
```

Before the `for-loop`. Documentation in [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

**Updated**:

If `$total` is affected in the loop (as you updated the question) then I believe best practice will be to counting array element first (without executing any more code), then echo the `$total`, afterward, loop on the original data and execute the rest of your code.

```
$total = 0;
foreach($pathList as $item) {
   $fileInfo = pathinfo($item);
   if(preg_match(strtolower('/\b'.$_POST['song'].'\b/'), strtolower($filename))) // or what ever condition you have to check for total
       $total = $total + 1;
}
echo count($total); // give you the count you need
foreach($pathList as $item) {
    // exec the rest of your code
}
```

This may run at `O(2*n)` but its not worse

Comment: I update my first question. I cannot use it echo count($pathList); because there is a condition on inside a loop. example if the total of pathList is 100 but after the condition it become 7. so the total result is 7 after the condition.

Comment: how about the echo inside the loop appear only once after completed the loop?

Comment: thanks I did what you said and its solved. my question is the one foreach loop and two foreach loop has the same amount of time for the execution?

Comment: It depend on the code you execute there - time-complexity perspective - both the same of `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Lines are executed in the order in which they appear in the script.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $total at the end of the loop is equal to the value of count($pathList)

If you need the value of the last iterated element of the $pathList before the execution of the loop, then it can be echoed as

```
echo $pathList[count($pathList)-1];
```

Comment: I update my first question. there is condition on inside a loop. I cannot use it echo $pathList[count($pathList)-1]; because there is a condition on inside a loop. example if the total of pathList is 100 but after the condition it become 7. so the total result is 7 after the condition.

Comment: In that case, you cannot echo the value of $total before the loop.  If there is no other echo statements inside the loop, then echoing $total before and after the loop doesn't make a difference.